# Regular expression to get text inside parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

I going to admit that I am hopeless at writing regular expressions. So can anyone please offer assistance in writing an expression (in C#) that will match the following cases:

```
value(Plugin.Tests.Business.Services.Repositories.Maps.SomeTests+<>c__DisplayClass2).
value(Plugin.Tests.Business.Interfaces.SomeOtherClass+<>c__DisplayClass3).
```

Ideally I'd like anything between the brackets to be matched. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^value\((.*)\)\.$");
```

Comment: what if string inside parentheses contains additional parentheses

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest investing in a tool like RegexBuddy. Give it a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have any parentheses inside the substring:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"^value\([^\)]+\)\.$");
```

Comment: Simply using `.*` is a better solution, unless you plan to be using something like the `Multiline` or `SingleLine` regex options